# Javascript/jQuery: Input always appears empty even if it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird problem that I can't seem to solve: I have built a live search with jQuery for a WordPress site. The search uses ".val" to get the input of the search field and pass it on but it always turns up empty even if it isn't.

The thing is, it works everywhere else on the site (always gets the value with

```js
var searchField = $('.gd-search-field-search .search_text'),

var query = searchField.val();
```

)
but on the landing page and an archive it doesn't. It's always identical - the search is integrated via widget and I've checked many times: all IDs, classes etc. are the same. Does anybody have an idea what could cause the conflict?

Comment: `.val()` returns the value of the first match, which is an empty field further up: https://jsfiddle.net/rfz49b7t/

Comment: Would be usefull to have the exact HTML you have for this.

Comment: Ah, now I feel stupid, how didn't I think of that. Indeed, there was another hidden instance of an input field matching the criteria further up the page for some reason... thanks a lot! @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't need to all classes for getting a value you can simply use

```
var searchField = $('.search_text');
var query = searchField.val();
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer